# Aurora mysql select to s3 hangs after completing

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-aurora

I'm running a large extract to an s3 bucket from an AWS Aurora cluster that uses the 5.6.mysql_aurora.1.22.2 engine. The query returns ~4.5 million rows of about 30 characters each, so it's not ginormous, but pretty big. I'm running it from a terminal on my Macbook by connecting via the mysql command line client and feeding it the query. By monitoring the s3 bucket, I see that it finishes the extract in about 20 minutes, but the mysql command in my terminal window never completes. After a couple of hours it finally just times out. Do I need to configure timeouts differently? Is there a better way to kick this off than the CLI?